# "Mysql expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in" type of error

Tags: php, mysqli

Got this MySQL function that's throwing up errors and since I clearly got the original code in deprecated MySQL, had to convert to mysqli compliant language but this below bugs me to a dead stop with the error

> mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in line 91

Line 91 equates to
`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, $arr_type))` in the code below.

```
 function getAll($query, $arr_type = MYSQL_ASSOC) {
    if (! $query)
        return array();

    if ($arr_type != MYSQL_ASSOC && $arr_type != MYSQL_NUM && $arr_type != MYSQL_BOTH)
        $arr_type = MYSQL_ASSOC;

    $res = $this->res($query);
    $arr_res = array();
    if ($res) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, $arr_type))
            $arr_res[] = $row;
        mysqli_free_result($res);
    }
    return $arr_res;
}
```

Comment: Place a `var_dump($arr_type)` just before the line that generates the error and post the result.

Comment: Needed "to use MYSQLI_ASSOC (note the I after MYSQL)". That was the culprit. All solved and okay. Many thanks to @dognose for spotting this. Saved me a mid-day crisis.

Answer (score 2):

The Second parameter is a constant which resolves to an integer.

https://secure.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

**resulttype**

> This optional parameter is a constant indicating what type of array should be produced from the current row data. The possible values for this parameter are the constants MYSQLI_ASSOC, MYSQLI_NUM, or MYSQLI_BOTH.

So you have to put the constant to your variable that you have the integer value. And like in the comments discussed it's `MYSQLI_ASSOC` not `MYSQL_ASSOC`.

Comment: Changed that line to use the function directly as in: "$arr_type != MYSQL_ASSOC && $arr_type != MYSQL_NUM && $arr_type != MYSQL_BOTH)
            $arr_type = MYSQL_ASSOC;"  Still, gives same error nonetheless

Comment: @CmailUltimate In other words: `$arr_type = 'MYSQL_ASSOC';` - don't use quotes here, as `MYSQL_ASSOC` is a constant that represents an Integer. (If your problem still exists, you might not even hitting that part of the code, cause you already set `$arr_type` to another string earlier?)

Comment: Try `constant` something like `constant($arr_type)` in your parameter. Perhaps that working.

Comment: @dognose corrected that. Its still gives me errors. Used the constant directly in all instances. Actually had the quote put there as I couldnt figure out what the fuck the problem is. But now that everyone is pointing to that as the first area to start from, quotes are off and yet I get the error even when its declared as a constant.

Comment: @CmailUltimate what does `var_dump($arr_type)` say, RIGHT before your `mysqli_fetch_array`-call?

Comment: @CmailUltimate guess you have to use `MYSQLI_ASSOC` (note the I after MYSQL)

Comment: @dognose Spot on Genius! Thanks man. Didnt know the deprecated mysql affects the Constant MYSQL_ASSOC. But sure, that was the culprit. Everything is prime and perfect now. Thanks for all the help.